# shopify mongodb connection

Tags: mongodb, shopify, webhooks, nosql

Recently, I came across this situation where I need to develop a connection between Shopify and MongoDB project. 
The situation is like this.

We have a management system, developing with MEAN stack techq. An inventory system which is managing through MongoDB. We want our inventory to be launched on the Shopify for more exposure.

I am new to Shopify and looking for guidance or right direction.

So far I can only think of:
Creating a web hook btw my application and Shopify and making MongoDB database as MASTER and Shopify db as a slave.

So we can perform CRUD operations on Shopify from our application. 
But I am afraid of **100% syncing between master and slave**.

What will be a right way to design this type of system.

I will be externally thankful for all the help/comments/suggestion from you guys in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot think of a platform like Shopify as a Slave to your needs in that fashion. Instead, you would use the API to ensure any changes you have in your MongoDB for products get pushed to Shopify via the API. If things happen with Shopify like orders that affect your inventory, you would use Webhooks to respond, they are a trigger for you to do things.

So your thinking is correct, you just need to refine your technical skills to ensure whatever you do outside Shopify is properly dealt with inside Shopify.